# How can I validate my estimated covariance matrix?

Tags: matlab, correlation, covariance

I have two covariances of size 6*6, one is supposed be the true covariance and the other is the Maximum likelihood estimate for my covariance. Is there any way I could validate my estimated covariance?

Comment: "error ellipses work only for..."  What does this mean?  Can you show the code that isn't working? You haven't even said what language this is.

Comment: in order to show covariance matrix using error ellipse, the covariance should be of size 2*2 or 3*3. this is the matlab script that does this: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4705-error-ellipse

Comment: You should edit your post to add the [tag:matlab] tag, and to include the code you're trying to get working *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly you determined your covariance matrix, but generally it is a good first step to check the confidence intervals of your estimators.

Heuristically speaking a wide confidence interval suggests that your estimator has a lot of uncertainty.

Take a look at the Matlab function corrcoef, which also gives lower and upper bounds for the estimated correlation coefficients,

cf. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html#bunkanr .

Maybe using this function on your data gives you a good starting point. If you use your own function to estimate the ML estimators, you will have to add the confidence intervals yourself.